# exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ")" laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

i am following tutorial on laravel 5 on laracast i am getting this error .

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ")":

```
Schema::create('articles', function(Blueprint $table)
    {


        $table->increments('id');
        $table->Integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->timestamp('published_at');


        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->refrences('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on "refrences('id). Your migration should look like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Test extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->timestamp('published_at');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
     }

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('articles', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropForeign('articles_user_id_foreign');
        });
        Schema::drop('articles');
    }

}
```